# How to list all directories/files that you have copy access permission to - Unix

Tags: unix, directory, copy, ls, access-rights

Normally, the `ls -la` command shows the files and the copy access rights, owners and access group. 
**

- **How can I list only list the directories/files that I have access to?**
- **How can I copy these directories/files to a destination directory?**

Comment: Access is defined as read/write/execute in simple terms. Which one you are referring to?

Comment: rights to copy, so i assume that's write/execute access.

Comment: For the first part `How can I list only list the directories/files that I have access to?` you just need read permissions on files and read/execute permissions on directories.

Comment: Do you actually need the list before the copy?  You could do a cp -pr src dest, then whatever gets copied is what you had access to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a=`find $Your_Source_Path -iname "yourFolder_whose_Files_tohide" -prune -o -type f -print`
for i in $a
do
   cp $Your_source $Your_Dest_Path
done
```

Comment: Here are two commands one is for find and second one is for cp so for enumerating the files its required.

Comment: what does `yourFolder_whose_Files_tohide` mean?

Comment: It means your any files which you want to hide. You can mention there with your specific file name.

Comment: i dont need to hide any specific file. i need to only ls all files i've copy access to. and then copy those files to a specific destination.

Comment: Try like this:-     find . -iname -prune -o -type f -print

Comment: sadly, it still lists the `permission denied` directory

Answer (score 0):

One more answer which will copy only those files whose having copy access permission. For this first navigate to the directory whose file wanted to copy. Also inside this mention your destination path first where you wanted to copy. Try the below:-

```
destination_Path="/Users/Home/Desktop/test"
b=~/Desktop/copyPermission.txt
if [ ! -f $b ]
then 
touch $b 
fi
a=`ls -l`
e="-----w--w-"
echo "\n$a" | sed '1d' > $b
g=`pwd`
while read line
do 
d=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ $e != $d ]
then
r=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $9}'`
echo "Can have copy permission $g/$r" 
{
cp $g/$r "$destination_Path" && echo "copied successfully"
} || {
echo "cannot copy due to some error"
}
#else
#r=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $9}'`
#echo "Cannot have copy permission $r"
fi
done <"$b"
```